# Designing a gui in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

I am learning to design a GUI in GWT
I have RootPanel where i have put all the widgets.

In one panel i have put tree Widget where the treeItems are added on the success of RPC call on the selectionHandler

What I want to do:
When click on treemItem , All the other treeItem and the widgets on the same and different panel should not be selected. Like there is a processing going on so no other things are allowed to do.

Please suggest some idea or sample code or example.

Comment: Have you found a solution? if not check GlassPanel  on DialogBox menu http://www.asquare.net/gwttk/apps/demo/Demo.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correctly understand you, you want to disable user clicking some widgets until specific callback finishes. In order to do that you should have a custom panel with bigger `z-index` and `opacity`. For example, something like `DialogBox`'s `setGlassEnabled(true)` method and try using that technique in your callbacks. When asynchronous request starts show that panel in `onSuccess` and `onFailure` you should hide it. By the way, my-gwt has [LoadingPanel](http://code.google.com/p/my-gwt/source/browse/trunk/user/src/net/mygwt/ui/client/widget/LoadingPanel.java?spec=svn311&r=311) class which implements such feature. And also another [mask](http://gwt-ext.com/demo/#mask) live demo in GWT-Ext.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is redundant and unnecessary:

> "When click on treemItem , All the other treeItem and the widgets on
>   the same and different panel should not be selected."

Of course, when you click on a tree node, that is the only node you want activated. No other node would have any activity. That is by convention.

And I really don't know what this statement is all about:

> "Like there is a processing going on so no other things are allowed to
>   do."

**Your question should simply be:**

> How do I add child nodes to a tree Widget, where child nodes are added
>   only when I click on the node? When I click on a node, if it has no
>   child nodes, an RPC would be triggered to fetch the nodes. How should
>   my RPC results update the node? After I click on a node, it should be
>   highlighted. There should be only one highlighted/selected node on the whole tree.

Extend HorizontalPanel to contain an icon and a title.
It should implement IsTreeItem.
It should implement ClickHandler so that it can be added as clickhandlers to the icon and title label.

```
public class Node
extends HorizontalPanel
implements ClickHandler, IsTreeItem{
  Image img;
  Label label;
  MyData data;
  TreeItem nodeWrapper;
```

The constructor eats in a MyData record, instantiates the icon image and title label, and associates itself as the clickhandler for the icon and label:

```
  public Node(MyData data){
    this.nodeWrapper = new TreeItem(this);
    this.img = new Image(data.getIconUrl());
    this.label = new Label(data.getTitle());
    this.data = data;
    this.add(img);
    this.add(this.label);

    // ensure onclick is triggered either by clicking img or label.
    this.img.addClickHandler(this);
    this.label.addClickHandler(this);
  }
```

Implementing IsTreeItem requires the node to be able to substantiate itself with a TreeItem:

```
  public TreeItem asTreeItem(){
    return this.nodeWrapper;
  }
```

The clickhandling will fetch the list of child records and iteratively create new nodes from the child records and attach them to the current node. This is where the RPC callback action takes place.

```
  public void onClick(ClickEvent e){
    this.displayRightPanel(this.data);

    if(this.nodeWrapper.getChildCount()==0)
      fetchNodeData(
        this.nodeWrapper,
        this.data.getId(),
        new AsyncCallBack<List<MyData>>(){
          public void onSuccess(List<MyData> nodeDataList){
            for(MyData nodeData : nodeDataList){
              Node.this.nodeWrapper.addItem(new Node(nodeData));
            }
          }
          public void onFailure(Throwable sorry){
            doWhatever();
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

define other relevant methods before closing the class definition:

```
  //blah ... blah ... blah...
}
```

Since this is not a tutorial on RPC, you should find out how to write the RPC part. You need to define MyData which is a shared POJO between GWT client and RPC servlet. RPC servlet must return a list of MyData. You need to be educated on at least the 2nd Normal Form of database normalisation to understand why you need a getId() method.

```
public Interface MyData{
  String getIconURL();
  String getTitle();
  String getId();
  // among others ...
}
```

It is presumed that you have a splitpanel. The left side would be the tree widget and the right panel is some sort of display. So that onclick, besides triggering RPC fetch, would also call displayRightPanel(data), and it is left to you how you wish to display that data.

You would create a first root node and associate it as the root of the tree, and the rest of the tree would be populated by user clicking. So the root node would require you to concoct a MyData record that will supply the iconUrl, title, and some root data.

The tree widget will manage the highlighting of its members and ensure only one member is highlighted.